# How would you say “return to the stars” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, grammar-identification

How would you say “return to the stars” in Latin in the form of a command for instance. Does not need to be an aggressive version of the commas, simply a pleading.

Answer (score 5):

For a straightforward translation, assuming you're addressing a single person:

> Regredere ad astra.
> *Go back to the stars.*

*Regredī* is a nice, classic verb for "return" or "go back". *Ad astra* also shows up in a few other phrases, like *ad astra per aspera* (to the stars through difficulties), which helps recognizability too.

Comment: `redī` can also be used.